# If i stop CryptoStream Read i get Bad Data exception

Tags: c#, dispose, cryptostream

I'm having problem with CryptoStream Decryptor.
I'm decrypting file on another Thread.
So here is the problem:

When I let the file to decrypt to the end, everything is allright but when I stop thread, using global variable, and get out of while loop

```
while( !stopThread && ( nBRead = csFile.Read(readbuf, 0, 8192)) != 0)
```

I get Bad Data exception at the`cryptostream Dispose()`.

What i'm doing wrong ??

Here's my code:

```
            string ext; 
            //textBox1.Text = "";

            OpenFileDialog ofdFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (textMode)
                ofdFile.Title = "Please select text to decrypt.";
            else
                ofdFile.Title = "Please select file to decrypt.";

            OpenFileDialog ofdKey = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofdKey.Title = "Please select KEY.";


            // mora ovo ili invoke koga nema dialog :)
            originalContex.Send(delegate
            {
                dialogRes    = ofdFile.ShowDialog();
                dialogResKey = ofdKey.ShowDialog();
            }, null);


            if ( dialogRes == DialogResult.OK && dialogResKey == DialogResult.OK )
            {
                FileStream fsKey = new FileStream(ofdKey.FileName, FileMode.Open);
                byte[] iv = new byte[8];
                byte[] key = new byte[24];
                byte[] extB = new byte[20]; 
                fsKey.Read(iv, 0, 8);
                fsKey.Read(key, 0, 24);
                fsKey.Read(extB, 0, 20); 
                fsKey.Dispose();

                FileStream fsOpenedFile = new FileStream(ofdFile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                CryptoStream csFile = new CryptoStream(fsOpenedFile, new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);


                if (textMode)
                {
                    int readbuf;
                    List<byte> lb = new List<byte>();

                    while ((readbuf = csFile.ReadByte()) != -1)
                        lb.Add((byte)readbuf);

                    textBox1.Invoke( new MethodInvoker(() => { textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(lb.ToArray()); }) );

                    prog.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { prog.Value = 100; }));
                }                   
                else // filemode
                {
                    byte[] readbuf = new byte[8192];
                    ext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(extB).Trim('\0'); 


                    string saveDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofdFile.FileName) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofdFile.FileName) + "_DECRYPTED";
                    Directory.CreateDirectory( saveDir );
                    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory( saveDir );



                    FileStream fsDecrFile = new FileStream(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofdFile.FileName)  + ext, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofdFile.FileName);
                    long oneProc = fi.Length / 100;
                    int nBRead = 0;
                    long nBReadacc = 0;

                    while (   !stopThread  &&  ( nBRead = csFile.Read(readbuf, 0, 8192)) != 0  )
                    {
                        nBReadacc += nBRead;
                        fsDecrFile.Write(readbuf, 0, nBRead);

                        if (nBReadacc >= oneProc)
                        {
                            nBReadacc = 0;
                            prog.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { prog.Value +=1; }));
                        }
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        csFile.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (CryptographicException e)
                    {                        
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                    }

                   // MessageBox.Show(nBReadacc.ToString());

                    fsDecrFile.Flush();
                    fsDecrFile.Dispose();   

                    prog.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { prog.Value = 100; }));                   
                }



                fsOpenedFile.Dispose(); 
                // csFile.CopyTo



            }

            ofdFile.Dispose();
            ofdKey.Dispose();            
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide your complete code? My guess is that it is the writer/reader which is trying to flush to or read from the disposed stream.

Comment: Does it matter if you get an exception? As long as you close the file you're good, right? It's not like the data is corrupt the next time you're reading it

Comment: @Patric: I get that but I'm curious why am I getting this exception?

Comment: Obviously because that's how it's implemented. If the CryptoStream upon dispose does not have the correct padding according to its algorithm, an exception is thrown.

Comment: Just a small thing, you should wrap Streams in using statements. This makes sure of correct disposal. Thats not really the matter here but it saves time on trying to see it the dispose is correct especially in such nested things like this one here.

Comment: So I can ignore this exception? But I still don't understand why padding is involved when reading and stopping in the middle. Should padding be involved only at the last block?

Comment: Oh goodness. I ran into this exact problem. My situation is the same: I'm reading a `CryptoStream` and want to stop mid-way, but my `Dispose`/`Close` is exploding and complaining about padding. Do you have any further insight into this? Currently, I'm just skipping the `CryptoStream` and closing my `FileStream` directly. Does no one know the answer??? #DenverCoder9